# Can't Retrieve Data from MongoDB in django application

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to develop a website in Django. I am using MongoDB as a database for the first time. I used Djongo to develop the connection between django and MongoDB. I have created a  database  in the Robo3T and the connection is also developed between django and MongoDB. The data is saving fine in the database I have seen in the robo3T. But when I am trying to retrieve the data back from the MongoDB to dispay on the Django Template, its not shoiwng the data and show the template tag like this {{post.tile}} {{post.content}}.
Here is my code:

Setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':27017
    }
}
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView
from .forms import FormName
from .models import Post 
# Create your views here.

class MainPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name='main.html'

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name='login.html'

def RegistrationView(request):
    form=FormName()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("In Post")
        print(request.POST)
        form=FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

    else:
        form=FormName()

    return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form})
    
   
    # template_name='registration.html'

def main(request):
    post=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'main_temp.html',{'Post':post})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
# from OnlineJobPortal.settings import DBNAME

# # Create your models here.
 
# # connect(DBNAME)
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
class FormName(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=Post
        fields='__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template tags to
`{{ post.tile }}` etc.

The spaces make the difference since the template tags won't be interpreted correctly without.

[official docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score 0):

You have made a spelling mistake while accessing the field (`post.title` instead of `post.tile`) in your template. Your template coding structure should be somewhat similar to as follows.

```
{% for post in Post %}
    <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
    <span>{{ post.content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```